# Strange result from evaluating a Limit expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, version-9

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

When I evaluate the limit of `(1-Cos[x]) Sin[1/x]` at `x = 0` in *Mathematica* 9, I obtained `Interval[{-2, 2}]`. The problem is that this limit is 0. It is also 0 when I compute it by Maple and *Mathematica* 7. So, I wonder whether I've found a bug in *Mathematica* 9?

```
Limit[(1 - Cos[x]) Sin[1/x], x -> 0]
```

> ```
> Interval[{2, 2}]
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't write by mistake `(1+Cos[x]) Sin[1/x]`?

Comment: @Spawn1701D No. Please see the image added in my questions. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What subversion of 9 you have? Did you run the command after a initializing the kernel? If this is true its a big mess up! It's like saying that $\cos(0)=-1$!

Comment: It's working fine for me on 9.0.1. Make sure x doesn't have a value with x=. first.

Comment: Same result as OP here v 9.0.1 on WinXP

Comment: I'm getting 0 with M 9.0.1, both on OS X, Linux and Windows 8.  @belisarius It's funny that Limit would give different results on different computers.  Perhaps it has some `TimeConstrained` internals like `Integrate`?

Comment: @belisarius Can you try `Block[{TimeConstrained = (#1&)}, Limit[...]]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Same result!

Comment: Get zero when I evaluate OP expression with V9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I evaluated it with V9.0.1 on Win7 (32bit), while my friend got 0 with V9.0.1 on Win7(64bit). It's strange!@m_goldberg @Szabolcs

Comment: Just to give more odd results: If I evaluate `Limit[(1 - Cos[x]) Sin[1/x], x -> 0]` with 8.0.1 on Win7(32bit) I get 0, and with 9.0.0 on Win7(32bit) I get `Interval[{-2, 2}]`.

Comment: @Z-Y.L I also got `0` in *Mathematica* 9.0.1 Win7 64bit, fresh kernel. According to your last comment, I assume this is a 32bit issue.

Comment: So we know it's a 32-bit / 64-bit issue.  @Z-Y.L I guess there's not much more to say than that it's a bug ... could you report it to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: Sure. @Szabolcs

Comment: @Z-Y.L Did you get a reply from support?

Comment: @Szabolcs They have just filed a reporter with their developer. I'm afraid they have not resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.0.0.

```
Limit[(1 - Cos[x]) Sin[1/x], x -> 0]

(* 0 *)
```